# Ubuntu 12.04 2D mode after upgrading my Nvidia graphic driver

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on a T430s laptop that has a NVIDIA Optimus graphic card (NVS 5200M, 1GB). I tried to download and install the latest nvidia driver from [here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html). After restart, I found out that Ubuntu is running in 2D mode!

I tried to uninstall the nvidia driver using --uninstall switch and also purged all nvidia packages. Still no luck! What should I do? I need the openGL feature of my graphic card.

Edit: The only temporary solution I found right now is to use Bumblebe according to [here](http://followthegeeks.com/a-noobs-guide-to-installing-nvidia-optimus-driver-in-ubuntu/).

Answer (score 0):

First remove all Nvidia packages (if you haven't done so already):

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

Then install the current Nvidia drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Reboot, and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but it did not work!